# Riemann-Stieltjes Integral notation

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

What is the difference between

1) $∫_{0}^\infty xdf(x)$

and

2) $∫_{0}^\infty f(x)dx$

Comment: $\int 1d(x^2)=x^2+C$

Comment: Can you provide some context - where have you come across these two notations?

Comment: Do you by any chance mean $\int f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ vs. $\int \mathrm dx\,f(x)$? If so, these mean the same but are written differently for reasons. The first is more standard and the latter occurs in physics afaik.

Comment: In (2), $x$ is the dummy variable. In (1) the dummy variable is $f(x)$ – which could be better written in another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first form is usually interpreted as a [Riemann-Stieltjes Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral). When $f$ is differentiable, we have
$$
\int x\,\mathrm{d}f(x)=\int x\,f'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$